# Can't get R to do a line between years

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created a data set and I am having some issues with graphing it. I think it stems from the fact that the data set is quite small so R doesn't recognise my X axis as years but rather as continuous data. Therefore, my graph has 2020.5. So, I have to convert the years column using `as.factor(AshQuads$Year)` but then it refuses to connect the years with `geom_line`.

This is the code I have been using

```
ggplot(Ash_Quads, aes(x=Year, y=Quadrats, colour=factor(Ash)))+
  geom_point()+
  theme_bw()
```

and this is my data frame: [image: my_dataset]

I was wondering if anyone can help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest just leaving the x-axis as continuous, rather than converting it to a factor.  Simply provide the actual breaks you want for your x-axis, in this case, the years `2020:2022`

```
ggplot(df, aes(Year,Quadrats,color=Ash)) + 
  geom_point() + geom_line() + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=2020:2022)
  theme_bw()
```

[image: quadrats]

Answer (score 1):

One option is to set the `Year` to factor (as you mention), then add the group into `aes` (i.e., `group = Ash`). You also need to add `geom_line`, which you don't have in your code.

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(Ash_Quads, aes(x = factor(Year), y = Quadrats, colour = factor(Ash), group = Ash)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Or you can use `scale_x_continuous` to set the x-axis (so leave as continuous data and not convert `Year` to factor):

```
ggplot(Ash_Quads, aes(x = Year, y = Quadrats, colour = factor(Ash))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 2020:2022) +
  theme_bw()
```

**Data**

```
Ash_Quads <- structure(list(Year = c(2020, 2021, 2022, 2020, 2021, 2022), 
    Quadrats = c(37, 31, 13, 54, 56, 38), Ash = c("No Ash", "No Ash", 
    "No Ash", "Ash", "Ash", "Ash")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```